# Удаленные шаблонные функции

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

Есть ли разница между записью `First` и `Second` ?

```
template<class T>
void fun(T&& /*var*/) {}

// First
template<>
void fun<int>(int&& var) = delete;

// Second    
template<int>
void fun(int&& var) = delete;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первое - это специализация шаблона сверху для случая `fun<int>`, а второе - перегрузка для вызовов типа `fun<4>`.

Comment: А можно чуть поподробнее что такое `fun<4>`  и как такое можно вызвать :(

Comment: @Антон Просто вызов шаблонной функции, просто вместо типа параметром шаблона является число.

Comment: хм, а я и не знал что так можно. А есть какой-то практический смысл у такого ? Или это из разрядов - С++ богатый язык и что не запрещено, то разрешено

Comment: @Антон Ну вот например класс `::std::array` позволяет указывать размер массива во время компиляции через параметр шаблона.